# Animate Jquery onclick event with window.scrollTo

Tags: jquery, onclick, anchor, scrollto

I am using an onclick event to target an anchor on a page....

```
<a href="#" target="LinkTarget" onclick='window.scrollTo(0,350);'>
```

I would like to use JQuery animate to make this target scroll smooth.

My JS also contains this which works on a #top anchor, but not sure how to apply it to the specific anchor above.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();    
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 60
        }, 800);
    });
```

Comment: Your second snippet is pretty much doing what your inline binding is doing, just with a variable top value.  And they seem to be targeting the same element(s) so I'm not sure how you are not seeing some sort of conflict currently.

Comment: The second snippet returns to the top of the page with a smooth scroll.
The top snippet, jumps to the anchor tag - I need this to scroll with animation also. Two different links - scrollTop and scrollTo @Taplar

Comment: Right, so what I was sort of eluding to is that, you should potentially make the child selector for that top logic exclude the other link.  And then you can make another similar to it, targeting the link, which performs the different calculation for the scrollTop that you desire.